# Error when using the tasks package

Tags: lists

I have recently downloaded the `tasks` package which align a list horizontally in columns by using an environment `tasks`, And tried it on this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
\settasks{counter-format = tsk/}
\begin{tasks}(2)

\task $f(x)=3x+4$  
\task $f(x)=2x^4+3x^3-x^2+17$  
\task $f(x)=cos(x)sin(x)$  
\task $f(x)=\dfrac{4x}{\sqrt{x}}$  
\task $f(x)=x^2-1$
\task $f(x)=(x^2-1)\sqrt{x}$
\task $f(x)=\dfrac{-2}{x+1}$ 
\task $f(x)=(-x-2)^2$

\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

when compiled with PdfLaTeX i have error

> ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a
>   missing \item.

and we have no result in the preview part (my IDE is  texmaker), but the PDF File appears in the tex file directory
[image]
how to solve this problem with `tasks`, and is there other packages to do this?

Comment: BTW: why download the package? It is part of both TeX Live and MiKTeX...?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the empty line at the beginning before the first `\task` and the error is gone.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\settasks{counter-format = tsk/}
\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task $f(x)=3x+4$  
  \task $f(x)=2x^4+3x^3-x^2+17$  
  \task $f(x)=\cos(x)\sin(x)$  
  \task $f(x)=\dfrac{4x}{\sqrt{x}}$  
  \task $f(x)=x^2-1$
  \task $f(x)=(x^2-1)\sqrt{x}$
  \task $f(x)=\dfrac{-2}{x+1}$ 
  \task $f(x)=(-x-2)^2$
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

The `tasks` list is not a list in the sense it is used usually in LaTeX, i.e., it doesn't actually use LaTeX's list mechanism (this is explained in the manual).  It tries to mimic the behavior, though. LaTeX's lists issue `\@noitemerr` if you add text before the first `\item`. `tasks` mimics this by testing if everything between the start of the environment and the first `\task` is blank (contains only of spaces) or not. If it isn't it issues `\@noitemerr`. Since a blank line (nearly) always implicitly inserts a `\par` token and a `\par` token is not a space you get the error. (IMHO since you don't want to end a paragraph there the empty line is wrong, anyway.) If you want an empty line in your source for whatever reasons then comment it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\settasks{counter-format = tsk/}
\begin{tasks}(2)
%
  \task $f(x)=3x+4$  
  \task $f(x)=2x^4+3x^3-x^2+17$  
  \task $f(x)=\cos(x)\sin(x)$  
  \task $f(x)=\dfrac{4x}{\sqrt{x}}$  
  \task $f(x)=x^2-1$
  \task $f(x)=(x^2-1)\sqrt{x}$
  \task $f(x)=\dfrac{-2}{x+1}$ 
  \task $f(x)=(-x-2)^2$
%
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

BTW: you also don't want the empty line at the end: [the newest version of `tasks` (v0.10a) adds a `\strut` at the end of an item](https://github.com/cgnieder/tasks/issues/5) which starts a new paragraph if the line before it was empty and as a consequence adds vertical space that you don't want.

Another BTW: you really shouldn't write `cos(x)sin(x)` but `\cos(x)\sin(x)`. Typing `$sin(x)$` means »s times i times n times x« (or more likely »s times i times n of x«) while `$\sin(x)$` means »sine of x«. Compare the first (wrong) with the second (correct) version:

[image]

This prints sin and cos in an upright font (like math operators should be) and also affects the spacing. You'll find a number of questions and answers regarding this topic on TeX.sx.

Comment: Please, use `\cos` and `\sin`, with a note explaining why.

Comment: @egreg I didn't notice them, thanks. I added something.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to load `amsmath` (or better, `mathtools`), where `\dfrac` is defined and delete the blank lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\settasks{counter-format = tsk/}
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $f(x)=3x+4$
\task $f(x)=2x^4+3x^3-x^2+17$
\task $f(x)=\cos(x)\sin(x)$
\task $f(x)=\dfrac{4x}{\sqrt{x}}$
\task $f(x)=x^2-1$
\task $f(x)=(x^2-1)\sqrt{x}$
\task $f(x)=\dfrac{-2}{x+1}$
\task $f(x)=(-x-2)^2$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]